# Column count doesn't match value count at row.How to match the value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets

i am working with inserting data into mysql database using jsp why it was not entering into database.the error is showing that "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
can anyone solve my problem and say where I've gone wrong please help me frnds

```
 java code
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Dealer extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException

{
int a1=0;
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();


    String dealId=request.getParameter("dealer_id");
    System.out.println(dealId);

    String dealName=request.getParameter("dealer_name");
    System.out.println(dealName);

    String doorNo=request.getParameter("door_no");
    System.out.println(doorNo);

    String street=request.getParameter("street");
    System.out.println(street);

    String city=request.getParameter("city");
    System.out.println(city);

    String district=request.getParameter("district");
    System.out.println(district);

    String state=request.getParameter("state");
    System.out.println(state);

    String pinCode=request.getParameter("pin_code");
    System.out.println(pinCode);

    String mob=request.getParameter("mobile");
    System.out.println(mob);

    String contactPerson=request.getParameter("contact_person");
    System.out.println(contactPerson);

    String phoneNo=request.getParameter("phone_no");
    System.out.println(phoneNo);

    String emailId=request.getParameter("email_id");
    System.out.println(emailId);

    String fax=request.getParameter("fax");
    System.out.println(fax);

    String crdOffI=request.getParameter("credit_offered_i");
    System.out.println(crdOffI);

    String crdOff=request.getParameter("credit_offered");
    System.out.println(crdOff);

    String vendorRating=request.getParameter("vendor_rating");
    System.out.println(vendorRating);

    String gstNo=request.getParameter("gst_no");
    System.out.println(gstNo);

    String cstNo=request.getParameter("cst_no");
    System.out.println(cstNo);

    String remarks=request.getParameter("remarks");
    System.out.println(remarks);


    String saveOrUpdate = request.getParameter("hiddenValue");
    System.out.println(saveOrUpdate);



try

{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

System.out.println("driver loaded");
System.out.println("Driver is loaded");
Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charms?user=root&password=root");
System.out.println("Connection created");
PreparedStatement ps =null;
    if(saveOrUpdate.equals("update"))
    {
        ps= ((java.sql.Connection) con).prepareStatement("update dealer_masters set deal_name_v =?, deal_door_no_v =?, deal_street_v =?, deal_city_v =?, deal_district_v=?, deal_state_v=?, deal_contactperson_v=?, deal_phone_no_v=?, deal_mobile_no_v=?, deal_faxno_v=?, deal_email_id_v=?, deal_creditoffered_i=?, deal_period_v=?, deal_vendor_rating_v=?, deal_CST_No_v=?, deal_GST_No_V=?,Remarks_v =? where deal_id_v=? ");

        ps.setString(1,dealName);
        ps.setString(2,doorNo);
        ps.setString(3,street);
        ps.setString(4,city);
        ps.setString(5,district);
        ps.setString(6,state);
        ps.setString(7,pinCode);
        ps.setString(8,contactPerson);
        ps.setString(9,phoneNo);
        ps.setString(10,mob);
        ps.setString(11,fax); 
        ps.setString(12,emailId);
        ps.setString(13,crdOffI);
        ps.setString(14,crdOff);
        ps.setString(15,vendorRating);
        ps.setString(16,cstNo);
        ps.setString(17,gstNo);
        ps.setString(18,remarks);
        ps.setString(19,dealId);


        a1=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(a1==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Inserted");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("status1", "updatesuccess");
        }

    }
    else
    {   

         ps= ((java.sql.Connection) con).prepareStatement("insert into dealer_masters(deal_id_v,deal_name_v, deal_door_no_v, deal_street_v, deal_city_v, deal_district, deal_state_v, deal_contactperson_v, deal_phone_no_v, deal_mobile_no_v, deal_faxno_v, deal_email_id_v, deal_creditoffered_i, deal_period_v, deal_vendor_rating_v, deal_CST_No_v, deal_GST_No_V,Remarks_v) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,dealId);
            ps.setString(2,dealName);
            ps.setString(3,doorNo);
            ps.setString(4,street);
            ps.setString(5,city);
            ps.setString(6,district);
            ps.setString(7,state);
            ps.setString(8,pinCode);
            ps.setString(9,contactPerson);
            ps.setString(10,phoneNo);
            ps.setString(11,mob);
            ps.setString(12,fax); 
            ps.setString(13,emailId);
            ps.setString(14,crdOffI);
            ps.setString(15,crdOff);
            ps.setString(16,vendorRating);
            ps.setString(17,cstNo);
            ps.setString(18,gstNo);
            ps.setString(19,remarks);


        a1=ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Inserted");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("status1", "success");
    }

}
catch(Exception e1)

{

System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
request.getSession().setAttribute("status1", "fail");
}

    response.sendRedirect("dealer.jsp");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement:

```
insert into dealer_masters(
deal_id_v,
deal_name_v, 
deal_door_no_v, 
deal_street_v, 
deal_city_v, 
deal_district, 
deal_state_v, 
deal_contactperson_v, 
deal_phone_no_v, 
deal_mobile_no_v, 
deal_faxno_v, 
deal_email_id_v, 
deal_creditoffered_i, 
deal_period_v, 
deal_vendor_rating_v, 
deal_CST_No_v, 
deal_GST_No_V,
Remarks_v) /* 18 columns */
values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) /* 19 parameters*/
```

The column list contains 18 columns but the values list contains 19 parameters.  I assume you added an extra parameter or missed a column.  The SQL statement must be change so the list of columns and parameters is of equals size.

Comment: @saideep Glad to hear you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

There are 18 bind parameters used in your query but you are setting 19 it seams another `deal_creditoffered` is missing